# Email newsletter not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm new in CSS and HTML. I have an email template with HTML and CSS code.
I put a pink circle box in my newsletter template to the top right: http://www.pedersenshotell.se/newsletter/

It looks OK on Firefox, Opera etc., but when I upload it to the Newsletter email campaign and send to Yahoo, Gmail, Outlook and Hotmail it looks so ugly. It shows a square box instead of a circle. Why?

Comment: does not it connect with security issue of free mail services when they block all external content like images, css and so on?

Comment: Please show some of the problem code here. Otherwise, this question loses its value to future generations once the problem is solved

Comment: Newsletters in email campaign tools like (outlook, gmail, hotmail) has less CSS support. border-radius is supported for web browsers not for email clients. It is better to use images instead of using CSS for newsletters.

Answer (score 6):

HTML e-mails are tough things. The email clients are often not normal browsers they don't render the HTML correctly and you'll be surprised why a normal thing (like background) is not working there.

The web services are removing/blocking parts for security reasons and so on.

I would stick with HTML 3.2 or simpler HTML solutions which are pretty annoying I know, and I recommend you to use [Fractal](http://getfractal.com/) which is an email validator service to check your work.

You can get hints from the [Email Standards Project](http://www.email-standards.org/) as well to see which functions are supported and which are not.

Ahh, and I almost forgot the most important part. Please provide a web link on the top of the mail to provide a web based view of the newsletter, as usually "View this message as a Web page" or "Click here if the email is broken".

Comment: Wow. Fractal It's really awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I suspect that the page has a square box instead of a round one because you are viewing it in a browser that doesn't support the `border-radius` property.</strike>

Please see [`border-radius`](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) for which browsers and versions have support for this property.

E-mail client support for border-radius is non-existent.

One solution here is to use a `<img>` instead of a CSS generated shape, although you may also find that e-mail clients block external content - a security feature which could result in a page that looks worse due to broken images. Since you have other images on the page already this may not be a problem for you.

Comment: A lot of styling is indeed lost when using e-mail clients, sadly.

Comment: `background-image` is also not supported for email clients. See the reference I gave. I suggest to use `<img>' for shapes, gradients, images or any 3d stuff.

Comment: @Ahsan thanks! I have corrected and am upvoting your answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Newsletters in email campaign tools like (outlook, gmail, hotmail) has less CSS support. Moreover, `border-radius` is supported for web browsers not for email clients.

It is better to use `<img>` for background images, pure images, gradients, round corners and 3d related stuff instead of using CSS styling.

See this reference: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

This reference shows which CSS property is supported by different email clients.

Answer (score 1):

It is VERY important to make you aware that browsers and email clients have 2 completely different ways of handling HTML and CSS.

You can never make it 100% compatible in all clients using CSS and HTML in newsletters. The only way, in my experience, to make newsletters 100% compatible is by writting the CSS inline in the HTML tags, like so:

`<td style="height:50px; width:100px; color: red; font-size: 12px; font-family: verdana;"> Content goes here </td>`

Comment: You don't have to do this, you can write it with a separate stylesheet and then use MailChimp's CSS Inliner tool: http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

Answer (score 0):

As already stated HTML email clients have some issues which have to be considered. The most important issue: Inline your CSS styles (most of the time).

To help building HTML emails there are some nice boilerplate templates. Take a look at http://www.emailology.org/#1 or https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate and use these templates as a starting point.